# Запятая перед союзом "как" (сравнение и отождествление)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, как, сравнение

Все мы знаем условия обособления союза "как", чаще всего это сравнение или же придаточное предложение, и мы везде, не задумываясь, ставим запятые перед "как"... Так вот, есть ещё одно условие -  "отождествление", при котором мы не ставим запятую. 
Как понять, когда мы употребляем отождествление или сравнение? Желательно с примерами...
Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 2):

Обособление оборота с союзом КАК зависит от его значения и синтаксической роли.

**Общее решение:**

1)  В соответствии со значением обороты с союзом КАК можно разделить **на две группы:**  сравнительный оборот: a как b; оборот со значением тождества: a = b;

2) В большинстве случаев **сравнительный оборот** обособляется (условно говоря, это попутное сравнение как дополнительное сообщение).

Сравнительный оборот не обособляется, если является **сказуемым  или  обстоятельством в основном сообщении.**

3)  Оборот с союзом КАК со значением **тождества** не обособляется, если тесно связан по смыслу со сказуемым или является обстоятельством **со значением «в качестве».**

Оборот со значением тождества обособляется, если является **аналогом придаточного предложения  со значением причины**.

Примеры:

1) **Сравнительный оборот**

Внизу, **как зеркало стальное**, синеют озера струи. Воздух чист и свеж, **как поцелуй ребёнка.**

Весёлая песня **как крылатая птица.** **Как ребёнок** душою я стал. В баснях звери ведут себя **как люди**. Тропинка извивается **как змея** (по-змеиному). **Как град** (градом) посыпалась картечь.

2) **Оборот со значением тождества**

Комендант посоветовал  мне оставить стихотворство, **как дело службе противное** (значение причины).

Все относились к нему **как к чудаку**. Смотрите на меня **как на пациента.** Я говорю **как литератор.** Любое внимание к своему творчеству он воспринимал **как похвалу** (значение в качестве, считая, рассматривая).

Answer (score 1):

Читаем у Розенталя:

> 4. Сравнительный оборот с союзом как не выделяется запятыми:
>
> 1) если на первый план выступает значение обстоятельства образа
>   действия (обороты с как можно заменить в этих случаях формой
>   творительного падежа существительного или наречием): Как град
>   посыпалась картечь (Л.) — ср.: градом посыпалась; Как демон коварна и
>   зла (Л.) — ср.:демонически коварна;
>   2) если основное значение оборота
>   — приравнивание или *отождествление*: …Ты любил меня как собственность,
>   как источник радостей, тревог и печалей (Л.) — ср.: …любил меня,
>   считая своей собственностью (**‘отождествляя меня со своей
>   собственностью’**); Старайтесь смотреть на меня как на пациента,
>   одержимого болезнью, вам ещё неизвестной (Л.) — ср.: **…приравнивая меня
>   к своим пациентам’**, [Иудушка] подавал свой камень как единственное,
>   что он мог дать (С. Щ.)[16];

Отождествление = тождественно, т.е. одно и то же:

*Смотрю на тебя как на победителя.* = Вижу тебя победителем.